# How do I align an absolute position child element in the center of its parent div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to make a kind of menu where consists of many DVD covers. When the cursor is positioned over each cover it will show the complete title name in a single line (not wrapped inside the cover container). How can I align the title right in the center of each cover.

Note: I would like to place the title a bit above the cover, not completely over it.

Here is the HTML example:

```
<div id="cover"><span>Here is the title in a single line!</span></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#cover{
height:200px;
width: 150px;
background-color:#00f;
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#cover span{
position:absolute;
background-color:#0f0;
display:none;

}

#cover:hover span{
display:block;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rQW3T/)

Comment: it would be easiest to make a jsfiddle of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *When the cursor is positioned over each cover it will show the 
>   complete title name in a single line (not wrapped inside the cover 
>   container). How can I align the title right in the center of each 
>   cover.*

I think this will take care of it.

[**Codepen.io Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/lGbBK)

**CSS**

```
.cover{
  height:200px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color:#00f;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position: relative;
}

.cover span{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#0f0;
  display:none;
  color:white;

}

.cover:hover span{
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;  
  top:10%; /* adjust to suit */
  width:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

> *I would like to place the title a bit above the cover, not completely*
>   *over it.*

I'm not sure what this means but the vertical positon can be adjusted by means of the `top` value.

Comment: WOW it's exactly what I was looking for!!!! Thank you so much Paulie_D

Comment: You are welcome. Please note that it uses CSS3 transforms which are pretty well supported but not universally. ( http://caniuse.com/transforms2d ) When you are ready please mark as the answer.

Comment: The secret was the transform but it seems not to work with IE8, is it there any work around to fix this compatibility issue?

Comment: Not really...because you don't know the width of the text. If you do, you can omit the transform and just use a negative margin-left of 50% of the width. IE8 version - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/olgeJ

Answer (score 1):

"Piggybacking" on @Paulie_D's answer, I would include the element's properties in the 'normal' state rather than on the `:hover` state. Two benefits of this:

- The element's properties don't need to be applied on every `:hover` action, hence optimizing elements' repaint a bit.
- Just in case you want to show that content on the 'normal' state, the element will already have all the styles applied to it.

Here's what I mean:

```
.cover {
  height:200px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color:#00f;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position: relative;
}

.cover span {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#f00;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:auto;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;  
  top:10%; /* adjust to suit */
  display: none;
}

.cover:hover span{
  display:block;
}
```

**Truth be told though:**

Using `:hover` to display content is a content strategy and user experience bad practice: http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-hover-menus-do-users-more-harm-than-good/

Not only that but the content cannot be seen in touch screen devices, which renders this approach completely unusable.

Good luck.

Comment: I was in a rush but these are all good points worth mentioning. +1